# Retaining login credentials inside Mobile XPage added to Home Page

Tags: ios, xpages, xpages-extlib

I have an application built using XPages' mobile controls. On an ipHone the application behaves as I would like in the standard Safari browser. When I take the url and add it to the Home Page as an icon and use the application from there every time an action I take invokes a native application (Maps, Contacts, Phone, attachment viewers etc.) when I switch back to my application I am immediately asked for my userid and password again. Is there a way to control the behavior to not lose the login credentials the same way that the standard Safari application seems to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the secret to success here is NOT to tell Safari the XPage is capable of acting as a mobile web app. Add the following code inside  for the XPage to ensure this is the case.

```
<xp:metaData
  name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable"
    content="no">
</xp:metaData>
```

Note: You can still provide an icon for the home screen, its just that icon will now act more like a bookmark with the Safari controls and (more importantly) you can switch between applications and when you return to Safari it will display your Xpages app just as you left it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation in iOS.  If you save it to the home page like that it works, but it will NOT multi-task.  That's the problem.  So it doesn't remember where you were or anything like that.

Comment: Sadly true. Depending on complexity, you could try a cookie or local storage approach, but no easy off switch for mobile safari webapp/full screen. [more explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7981418)

Answer (score 1):

As David mentions it starts all over again when you switch back.... The problem is not only the credentials - it is also all the information you may have entered or where you have navigated to in the "app".

This is why I am changing to another approach. I am starting to write apps as web-apps that run locally (i.e. cache the ressources and run on the cached versions of the JS-files, CSS and images). Then I implement a localstorage where you can track where in the app you are - and return to that place again. This way you do not *need* the authentication for running the app - only for synchronizing the information with the server. My approach is to save data locally and sync them to the server (as a sort of replication). This obviously gives more work - but it also gives a better user experience since you can run the "app" without being connected.

I have tried to control the caching locally using a cache.manifest file. This can be done, however, it is a pain. Therefore, I am now using Sencha Touch which really does this nicely.

/John

PS. I think you may be able to handle the login issue by using the XPage Dojo login custom control (http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=Xpages%20Dojo%20Login%20Custom%20Control) - however, it does not solve the issue with reloading the page...